# How to Hide Report Problem AlertTextView?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I want to Hide *Report Problem* alertText. I already hide alert icon

```
navigationView.findViewById(R.id.feedbackFab).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeRB7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide AlertView

```
navigationView.retrieveAlertView().updateEnabled(false);
```